# 12.04.2 lags when I have 4GB RAM

Tags: 12.04, installation, internet, intel-graphics, lts

i have ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS the newest version and it lags some times i have it running on a external drive wd book with 500 gb and the computer i have it hooked up to is a optiplex 755 with 4gb of ram help me thanks and what are the ram requested

Answer (score 1):

You've got enough RAM. I think the actual problem is that you are running the os on an external drive (via USB [2.0]?). This probably slows the processing down.

If you want to use both Ubuntu and Windows you could inform yourself about [dual boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) (if you want to use Windows for gaming) and [VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox) (if you want to use Windows for general tasks like Microsoft Office).